# Robot framework - generate random data

Tags: python, selenium, random, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a problem with generating the random string in robot. I am very new in robot and really dont know how to figure it out..
I found some solutions here and I tried to follow then, but I am doing something wrong obviously..
I got this error message in console: **No keyword with name '${random_string} = Generate Random String' found.**
My test case:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library    String
Resource   resource.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Add New Project
    ${random_string} = Generate Random String    12    [LOWER]
    Fill In Project Mandatory Fields    ${random_string}   descriptiondunno
    Verify Added Project
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

In the resource file I have defined the keywords I am using in test:

```
Fill In Project Mandatory Fields
    [Arguments]  ${random_string}    ${description}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${PROJECT TITLE}
    Input Text    ${PROJECT TITLE}   ${random_string}
```

and also:

```
Verify Added Project
    [Arguments]    ${random_string}
    Click Element    ${PROJECTS}
    Table Should Contain    ${GRID}    ${random_string}
```

I really appreciate any help, because I am really lost in this now :(
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html

Comment: sure, you can see I tried to do something based on the documentation:  ${random_string} = Generate Random String    12    [LOWER]  but maybe I don't understand it well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you using as a separator?  Just spaces?  If so, maybe increase to using four spaces to clearly separate things

Based on the error it seems to think

`${random_string} = Generate Random String    12    [LOWER]`

is a keyword, this is not what you want, you only want it to consider Generate Random String a keyword.

Try the below and let us know what happens:

```
${random_string}=    Generate Random String    12    [LOWER]
```

Comment: Wooow thank you!!!! It works now, my test is finally passing :D I just have to get used to the syntax, spaces...thank you!!

Comment: no problem, glad to help, I think quite a lot of people use pipe delimiters here which seems quite clear, I just use spaces as it's what the whole team uses.